# Proving the limit of x to infinity of x!/x^x is 0

Tags: calculus, limits

I have found that the limit of x to infinity of x!/x^x is zero by doing this:

x^x = x*x*x*x...(x amount of times)
x! = x*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3)...(x amount of times)

So obviously, x^x grows much faster, because x is greater than x-1 and x-2 and x-3 and all those other terms. Therefore the limit must be 0.

But how to actually prove this with equations. And why does Wolfram Alpha disagree with me when I do the infinite summation of x!/x^x and it says by the limit test that the summation diverges:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x!%2Fx%5Ex,+j%3D0..infinity

Comment: The limit of a *sequence* and the sum of a *series* are different things ...

Comment: Are you calculating the limit of that sequence or the series of the sequence??

Comment: Regarding the WA link, note that you write x!/x^x, but sum over j...

Comment: The reason that wolfram alpha says your sum diverges is as  Wojowu says you used the variable $x$ instead of $j$ in that sum. On top of this you need to start the index at $j=1$ on wolfram because of its convention with $0^0$. you can see this here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+j!%2Fj%5Ej,+j%3D1..infinity Contrary to the answer youve accepted the sum actually does converge, and you can show this pretty easily with a comparison with $\sum \frac{2}{n^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it in terms of the form $\frac{n}{x}$, with $n$ varying from $1$ to $x$. Clearly this is bounded above by the first term, which is $\frac{1}{x}$, which is null, so the sequence tends to $0$.

> And why does Wolfram Alpha disagree with me when I do the infinite summation of x!/x^x and it says by the limit test that the summation diverges:

Because, while the sequence $$\left(\dfrac{x!}{x^x}\right)$$ converges, the series $${\sum}\dfrac{x!}{x^x}$$ does not.

Comment: But according to Khan Academy here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/modal/v/integral-test-intuition, the improper integral of a function is an upper bound for its infinite summation, proving a very good argument for its convergence. On Wolfram, when I integrate x!/x^x from 0 to infinity I get something around 2.51791766302214. Shouldn't that be an upper bound for the series' summation, proving its convergence?